# Need to build fully static linphone

Tags: compilation, sip, voip, linphone

I need to be able to copy a linphone 3.5.2 binary to other PCs without having to install it every time. I was trying to compile a portable linphone, however no configure args helped:

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-strict --disable-rpath --disable-shared \ 
--disable-x11 --enable-fast-install --enable-console_ui=yes --enable-gtk_ui=no  \
--enable-relativeprefix --enable-ipv6 --enable-nonstandard-gsm --enable-rsvp \ 
--enable-ssl --enable-video --enable-alsa --enable-portaudio --with-gnu-ld

ldd console/linphonec
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe7dff000)
libeXosip2.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libeXosip2.so.6 (0x00007fcf2a8b4000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fcf2a69d000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fcf2a2c7000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fcf2a05d000)
libsoup-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libsoup-2.4.so.1 (0x00007fcf29df1000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf29aa1000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf29851000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf2952d000)
libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fcf292e5000)
libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fcf29090000)
libortp.so.8 => /home/wk/linphone-3.5.2/oRTP/src/.libs/libortp.so.8 (0x00007fcf28e6c000)
libportaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libportaudio.so.2 (0x00007fcf28c4b000)
libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 (0x00007fcf2896a000)
libspeexdsp.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libspeexdsp.so.1 (0x00007fcf28757000)
libv4l1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libv4l1.so.0 (0x00007fcf28551000)
libv4l2.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libv4l2.so.0 (0x00007fcf28345000)
libavcodec.so.53 => /usr/lib64/libavcodec.so.53 (0x00007fcf27643000)
libavutil.so.51 => /usr/lib64/libavutil.so.51 (0x00007fcf27422000)
libswscale.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libswscale.so.2 (0x00007fcf271e1000)
libtheora.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libtheora.so.0 (0x00007fcf26fad000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fcf26da6000)
libvpx.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libvpx.so.1 (0x00007fcf26b06000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcf268fd000)
libXv.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXv.so.1 (0x00007fcf266f7000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcf264f3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcf262d5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcf25fde000)
libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007fcf25dc4000)
libosip2.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libosip2.so.7 (0x00007fcf25bad000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fcf25995000)
libosipparser2.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libosipparser2.so.7 (0x00007fcf25761000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcf253b6000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fcf25077000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fcf24e65000)
libosipparser2.so.6 => not found
libosip2.so.6 => not found
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fcf24c4d000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fcf248f6000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf246f2000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fcf244ea000)
libv4lconvert.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libv4lconvert.so.0 (0x00007fcf24274000)
libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007fcf23f5a000)
libx264.so.120 => /usr/lib64/libx264.so.120 (0x00007fcf23c0d000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007fcf2373e000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007fcf23511000)
libvo-aacenc.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libvo-aacenc.so.0 (0x00007fcf232f3000)
libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007fcf2307b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcf2ab20000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fcf22e5a000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fcf22c09000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fcf22a05000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fcf227ff000)
```

Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Nope.. There's a large variety of recursive dependencies. The biggest problem is libeXosip2

Comment: Has anybody done this yet?